# How to join Online Campaign matches with Split Screen mod?

Tags: steam, mods, left-4-dead-2

So we setup the Game-Banana/Game-MapsL4D2 [Split-Screen mod](http://www.gamemaps.com/details/5260) and it works GREAT for local-play.  However it's a bit iffy for Online play and I've only been able to get it to work on VERSUS matches so far.  We'd like to play online CAMPAIGN-mode but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Here are the the steps I follow with VERSUS-mode:

1. If I don't already have the server-iP then I join as single player.
2. After joining I access console to acquire the server-iP using "status" command or just by scrolling up to find it.
3. Exit match to main-menu and in console enter the following command:
   connect_splitscreen localhost "iP address + PORT go here" 2
4. If there's room when we come back in all is good, and we get to have fun.

I've been trying the same process for CAMPAIGN-mode and it just fails, every time the game starts it's single player not splitscreen.  I know my process above may be convoluted so if you know of an easier way please do tell, that and a way to join an ONLINE-Campaign matches in split-screen.

FYi: I have not tried any other Online Game Modes besides the two mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

According to a [Left 4 Dead 2 Splitscreen Guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=520001026) on the Steam Community, Official servers (run by Valve) no longer support splitscreen with a controller.

**However** you can still join online community (third-party) servers:

> ### Join an Online server in SplitScreen
>
> Yes! You can also play SplitScreen online (Every gamemode is playable online, campaign co-op, Versus, Scanvenger, Survival and Versus but ONLY on Community servers, you can't play online SplitScreen on Valve server's anymore after the recent updates)
>
> Once you've got the IP of the server, go back to the game, open Console and type:
>
> `connect_splitscreen localhost "IP of the Server Here" 2`
>
> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

According to the guide, you can use [GameTracker](https://www.gametracker.com/search/left4dead2/?) to find online community servers.